# Is it possible to change the color of the object explorer in SQL Management Studio 2012?

Tags: ssms

I Added the dark theme from visual studio to my SMSS 2012 but the Object explorer is still a bright white. Is there a way to change the color of this?

Comment: I do not think you can do that as 'Environment' section in Fonts and Colors is locked. You can change font but not color. :(

Answer (score -1):

I think it's not optional but you can try go to following menu item:

```
tools 
- options 
  - environment
    - fonts and colors
```

I couldn't find it but maybe you will.